# crowd tracking with opencv

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision, video-tracking

I am working on a crowd controlled soundsystem for a music festival. Music would be controlled by individuals and the crowd as a whole, more or less 500 people.

While searching for crowd tracking techniques, I stumbled upon this one http://www.mikelrodriguez.com/crowd-analysis/#density; Matlab code and dataset are enclosed. Are you aware of similar techniques, maybe simpler, based eg on blob detection? Do you have an idea about how well this one would perform in a real-time scenario? Is there a known way to do this with eg OpenCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my former colleagues implemented something similar (controlling a few motors according to crowd movement) using optical flow. You can analyze the frames of video from a camera, calculate optical flow between frames, and use the values to estimate the crowd movement.

OpenCV has support to perform the above tasks, and comes with good code samples. A desktop should be able to do this in real-time (you might have to tweak with image resolution).

I am not exactly sure how to interface between a C++ program and a sound system. Pure Data (PD) is an alternative, but it might not have much support for motion analysis.

Comment: the interface with a sound engine is the easy part for me. We would need some kind of 3 dimensional data, as you can see on the graphs on the link, which would be not only about movement but also density of people

Comment: [Here](https://www.hal.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/paper/2010/10%20Detecting%20Dominant%20Motion%20Flows%20In%20Unstructured%20structured%20Crowd%20Scenes.pdf) is a paper by my colleague, on calculating the motion. This is two dimensional, though.